# html5 tags making advertisement content semantic

Tags: html

I know that many Semantic tags are available in html5 for sectioning contents. This tags are also used by Search Engines. Now I want to display some adds in my article contents.

So my question is which tag is useful to denote that child contents are not related with the parent content.

> I know that there is no specific tag for display Advertisement  content. But I want to know which should be best to display ads in between article
>   tags to display ads. Such as `aside` or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no semantic HTML5 tag for ads, you could use **schema.org** properties to make SEO corresponding tags.

Resource: https://schema.org/WPAdBlock.

Example of div describing an add:

```
<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WPAdBlock">
    /*Advertising here */
</div>
```

For more on how to use microdata, look [here](https://schema.org/docs/gs.html). Wikipedia has a great [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microdata_%28HTML%29) about microdata and Google offers a [Structured data testing tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/).